# How can I make Firefox buttons the same polished appearance than Chrome buttons?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

## Examples of buttons in Firefox

[image]

[image]

## Examples of buttons in Chrome

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the checkboxes? The buttons look pretty much the same in this example.

Comment: Yes, exactly. To me the Chrome ones look much more polished. The screenshot might not show that well enough. Why are they different in the first place?

Comment: I added more examples. Please take a look at these.